# How to encode the character into UTF-8?

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion, unicode

As we know the `café` is `caf\xc3\xa9` after encode by UTF8:

```
>>> 'café'.encode('utf8')
```

> `b'caf\xc3\xa9'`

But if I use

```
ToCharacterCode["café", "UTF8"]
ImportString["café", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
```

> `{99, 97, 102, 195, 169}`
>
> `{99, 97, 102, 233}`

This not what I after, how to get the real utf8 code(`caf\xc3\xa9`)?

Comment: `195 base 10` is `c3 base 16`. `169 base 10` is `a9 base 16`. The result seems correct to me?

Comment: if you want to print the ascii and use hex for others, something like `If[# > 127, IntegerString[#, 16], FromCharacterCode[#]] & /@ 
 ToCharacterCode["café", "UTF8"]`

Comment: @CarlLange As your prompt, [`IntegerString[ToCharacterCode["café", "UTF8"], 16]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s3gG.png) can convert it. But `mma` have no easier method convert `caf\xc3\xa9` into `café` mutually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string `b'caf\xc3\xa9'` is the "real utf8 code" in some other language, not *Mathematica*. You can see the deconstructed UTF-8 in hexadecimal with:

```
BaseForm[ToCharacterCode["café", "UTF8"], 16]
```

If you have a bunch of such strings, understand that *Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language. This is a rewriting problem. A good way to do this is to convert your string to a more elementary expression and rewrite it.

```
hexReplace[l_List] := l //. {h___, 92, 120, a_, b_, t___} :> 
   {h, fromHexCode[a, b], t}
```

The replacement rule takes a list generated by `ToCharacterCode`, recognizes sequences starting with `{92,120}` ("\x"), feeds the following two codes to a function `fromHexCode`, and reassembles the list with the result inserted. `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) applies this transformation until it has found and replaced every match.

```
fromHexCode[a_, b_] := FromDigits[FromCharacterCode[{a, b}], 16]
```

`fromHexCode` takes a pair of integer character codes representing a pair of hex digits, and combines them into a single integer.

Now, compose a function that does the whole job:

```
hx2utf8[s_String] := FromCharacterCode[hexReplace[ToCharacterCode[s]], "UTF8"]

hx2utf8["caf\xc3\xa9"]
(* café *)
```

Comment: Thanks. since it is belong with *other language*, then `caf\xc3\xa9` cannot convert into `"café"` as you said?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work.